# я Android Studio схема форматирования кода

Tags: android, android-studio, xml, format

Как мне добиться такого автоматического форматирования текста в Android Studio:

```
<item android:id="@+id/nav_remove_ad" //Первый атрибут тега на одной строке с его именем(первый всегда android:id)
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_shop"
        android:title="@string/navMenu_removeAd" 

        //Установить свой порядок атрибутов

        /> //Закрытие тэга на новой строке
```

Для меня это важно, потому что я часто форматирую его вручную по этой схеме

Comment: File-Settings-Editor-Code style

Comment: я знаю, что там можно настроить CodeStyle. Но там нет тех моментов, которые мне нужны. Там только отступы и пробелы регламентируются

Comment: можно сделать подстановку кода с параметрами - там целый язык программирования, я делал простые вещи - меня впечатлило

Comment: @Style-7, где можно посмотреть обучение тому как это сделать?

Comment: Посмотрел, вам не подойдет, там только для Java/Kotlin: Editor - General- Postfix Completion

Comment: А нашел, Editor-General -  Live Templates, там есть Android XML

Comment: Документация по кнопке Help